# Why can't I output city to a text label, using an action button?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I've set up the location and all in the viewdidload. Pretty much the user will press a button and a label will show their current location (city).

> Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'placemark'

```
func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) ->String{
     self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
     var location:String
     location = placemark.locality
     println(location)
     return location
}

@IBAction func currentLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
          originTextField.text = displayLocationInfo(location)

}
```

Comment: var `location` is defined in function `displayLocationInfo()`. How are you accessing it in `currentLocation()`?

Comment: Try `originTextField.text = displayLocationInfo(yourPlacemark)`

Comment: originTextField.text = displayLocationInfo(location)         "Use of unresolved identifier 'location'

Comment: You should pass the placemark in `displayLocation()`  Try   `originTextField.text = displayLocationInfo(somePlacemark)`

Comment: edit'd. still an error.

Comment: Do you have a variable named `location` which is accessible to func `displayLocationInfo()`?

Comment: The error is because in your currentLocation() function `location` is not available. do you have a `location` variable declared in glodal scope?

Comment: You have to create a placemark based on the current location, then you have to pass that placemark to the func `displayLocationInfo()`

Comment: Thats what I'm doing in the code above?

Comment: No you are not. You have just created a function which is ready to accept placemark and return location. But you are never calling the function with a specific placemark

Answer (score 0):

That approach can fix your problem:

```
  func displayLocationInfo(placemark:CLLocationCoordinate2D) ->String{
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        originTextField.text = ("locations = \(placemark.latitude) \(placemark.longitude)")
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
       displayLocationInfo(locValue)
  }

  @IBAction func currentLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
          self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 
          // For use in foreground
          self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

          if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
          }
   }
```

Comment: I don't have a problem getting the location. The problem lies with ONLY placing the location in the originTextField.text label after the IBaction button is pressed.

Comment: your displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) func expects placemark type as CLPlacemark but you are sending undefined value name location in IBAction.

Comment: yes. if i send placemark.locality it still has error